# PHP Get "Start tag expected" sometime

Tags: php

```
$count = 11;
for ($i=11;$i>0;$i--)
{   
        $url = "http://bet.hkjc.com/racing/getXML.aspx?type=win&RaceNo=".$i;
        //$url = "http://www.astarsagent.com/race/getXML.xml";
        print_r($url."<br/>");
        $array = array();

        if (($response_xml_data = file_get_contents($url))===false)
        {
                    echo "Error fetching XML<br/>";
        } else 
        {
                 libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
                $data = simplexml_load_string($response_xml_data);
                 if (!$data) 
                 {
                             echo "Error loading XML<br/>";
                            foreach(libxml_get_errors() as $error) 
                            {
                                        echo "\t", $error->message;
                                         print_r("<br/><br/><br/>------------------------------------------------------------------------<br/><br/><br/>");
                                        retry;
                             }
                 } else 
                 {
                            $array = xml2array($data);
                            printpre($array[WIN]);
                            if(count($array[WIN]))
                            {
                                    break;
                            }else
                            {
                                     print_r("N".$i."<br/><br/><br/>");
                                     $count--;
                            }
                    }
         }  
}//End for


print_r("raceNum:".$count);
```

I want to count a number when the xml contain data. Mostly the parsing is successful.

Sometimes I will get

```
[Error loading XML Start tag expected, '<' not found] 

at the line 

[echo "Error loading XML<br/>";]
```

What's wrong there?

XML:

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<ROOT>
    <WIN DATE="26-04-2017" VENUE="HV" updateDate="26-04-2017" updateTime="19:15:54">
        <RACE NUM="1" TIME="191554" FINAL_COLLATE="1" ID="25328" PID="25420">
            <OUT TYPE="O" NUM="1" WILLPAY="2650" HF="1" BIG_DROP="0" ODDSDROP="7.14">2.6</OUT>
            <OUT TYPE="O" NUM="2" WILLPAY="6550" HF="3" BIG_DROP="0" ODDSDROP="0.00">6.5</OUT>
            <OUT TYPE="O" NUM="3" WILLPAY="19550" HF="0" BIG_DROP="0" ODDSDROP="0.00">19</OUT>
            <OUT TYPE="O" NUM="4" WILLPAY="12700" HF="0" BIG_DROP="0" ODDSDROP="0.00">12</OUT>
            <OUT TYPE="O" NUM="5" WILLPAY="3550" HF="2" BIG_DROP="0" ODDSDROP="7.89">3.5</OUT>
            <OUT TYPE="O" NUM="6" WILLPAY="134000" HF="0" BIG_DROP="0" ODDSDROP="0.00">134</OUT>
            <OUT TYPE="O" NUM="7" WILLPAY="11450" HF="0" BIG_DROP="0" ODDSDROP="35.29">11</OUT>
            <OUT TYPE="O" NUM="8" WILLPAY="19650" HF="0" BIG_DROP="0" ODDSDROP="29.63">19</OUT>
            <OUT TYPE="O" NUM="9" WILLPAY="18000" HF="0" BIG_DROP="0" ODDSDROP="0.00">18</OUT>
            <OUT TYPE="O" NUM="10" WILLPAY="36800" HF="0" BIG_DROP="0" ODDSDROP="0.00">36</OUT>
            <OUT TYPE="O" NUM="11" WILLPAY="30800" HF="0" BIG_DROP="0" ODDSDROP="0.00">30</OUT>
            <OUT TYPE="O" NUM="12" WILLPAY="75700" HF="0" BIG_DROP="0" ODDSDROP="0.00">75</OUT>
        </RACE>
    </WIN>
</ROOT>
```

Comment: Maybe it would be a good idea to look at the XML before the PHP?

Comment: check that $response_xml_data do include the xml content and validate your xml using http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_validator.asp (it seems correct anyway)

Comment: Will it be my loop frequency too high, the website block my access?

I have tried to set sleep(2) every loop, but still wrong.